# How to achieve vertical scrolling on a horizontal recyclerview and blocking moving to next page of viewpager when scrolled on horizontal recycler view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-scrollview

There is a `ViewPager`, Horizontal `RecyclerView` and a `ScrollView`. When the last item on the `RecyclerView` is reached, on swiping horizontally, the next page in the `ViewPager` is shown. As this is not that user friendly, I disabled moving to next page when swiped horizontally on the `RecyclerView`. But the `RecyclerView` is a part of the `ScrollView`. So the problem is, when I swipe up and down on the `RecyclerView`, the page does not go up or down. The page goes up and down only when swiped outside the `RecyclerView`. Is there a possibility to achieve both? i.e., move up and down the page when swiped on the `RecyclerView` and do not move to the next page when swiped horizontally on the `RecyclerView`. All this is implemented as a fragment and not as an activity.

The below code is used to disable moving to next page when swiped horizontally on the `RecyclerView`:

```
   public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent event){
    switch(event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        rv.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use custom Viewpager to block swip

```
public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setMyScroller();
    }

    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setMyScroller();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }

    //down one is added for smooth scrolling

    private void setMyScroller() {
        try {
            Class<?> viewpager = ViewPager.class;
            Field scroller = viewpager.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
            scroller.setAccessible(true);
            scroller.set(this, new MyScroller(getContext()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class MyScroller extends Scroller {
        public MyScroller(Context context) {
            super(context, new DecelerateInterpolator());
        }

        @Override
        public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy, int duration) {
            super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, 350 /*1 secs*/);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't I achieve this in a swipeable viewpager (default viewpager) ? @Ganesh Pokale

Comment: Yes this may be possible, but it may be affect your recyclerview touch.. so best solution is block viewpager swip